# Generalized Euler Characteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was asking myself what kind of generalizations of the euler characteristic are there? I've heard about the homotopy cardinality, but I was rather interested in a construction involving generalized cohomology/homology theories.

I mean one can define $\chi(x)= \Sigma (-1)^i b_i(X)$ for let's say a finite CW complex. The Betti numbers are defined in terms of the singular homology. The problem I see here is, that we can't generalize the Betti numbers without a problem since we need to know in which "category" our homology/cohomology theory lives. For example if we were looking at rational homology it wouldn't suffice to look at the $\mathbb{Z}$-rank (which would be the natural thing, since homology lives in $Ab$), rather we would have to look at the rational rank of our homology modules, since the homology theory $H_*(-,\mathbb{Q})$ lifts to the category of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces.

Maybe there is a generalized notion of Betti numbers or a construction, which gives the right thing (a construction involving $K_0(R)$ for a suitable ring would be a nice canidate I guess).

Comment: The Euler characteristic does not depend on which coefficient ring you use.

Comment: I'm not talking about a different coefficient ring. I'm talking about a different homology/cohomology theory!

Comment: This isn't really precisely what you're asking for but you may like Lurie's notes [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/281notes/Lecture13-Part2.pdf).